# re-using a linq variable

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2017

I am successfully using some linq to populate some variables but in order to make it more efficient I would like to avoid the current repetition when setting the variables nextMDTID, nextPatientID, nextCareID and nextMDTDate.
Can I create a variable to hold the data generated using the linq query and then re-use it to avoid the repetition?

```
    Dim thisPTOrder = (From p In ThisMDTData Where p.MDTID = Request.QueryString("MDTID") Select p.PTOrder).FirstOrDefault
    Dim nextPTOrder = thisPTOrder + 1
    Dim d = ThisMDTData.Where(Function(p) p.PTOrder = nextPTOrder And p.PTOrder <= p.PTOrder)
    Dim nextMDTID = (From p In ThisMDTData Where p.PTOrder = nextPTOrder And p.PTOrder <= p.MaxPTOrder Select p.MDTID).FirstOrDefault
    Dim nextPatientID = (From p In ThisMDTData Where p.PTOrder = nextPTOrder And p.PTOrder <= p.MaxPTOrder Select p.PatientID).FirstOrDefault
    Dim nextCareID = (From p In ThisMDTData Where p.PTOrder = nextPTOrder And p.PTOrder <= p.MaxPTOrder Select p.CareID).FirstOrDefault
    Dim nextMDTDate = (From p In ThisMDTData Where p.PTOrder = nextPTOrder And p.PTOrder <= p.MaxPTOrder Select p.MDTDate).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: Define it as an old fashioned Function and call it when desired?

Comment: What is `nextPTOrder`?

Comment: @Ofiris it is just a variable that is incremented by 1 conditionally

Comment: @Ofiris I've updated the question which may or may not help

Comment: Why do you think that would be 'more efficient'?   Because it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok maybe it wouldn't be more efficient that repetition doesn't look elegant

Comment: You can do with this easier with lambda syntax, but you can do this. If `ThisMDTData` is from a database, there is a tradeoff between returning more data than needed and querying the database four times. What is `ThisMDTData`? PS You already have `d` defined - why are you not using it?

Comment: @NetMage I'd like to use d in the subsequent variable declarations but it's not liking my syntax, so how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a proper definition for `d`, you can simplify the results extraction:

```
Dim d = ThisMDTData.Where(Function(p) p.PTOrder = nextPTOrder And p.PTOrder <= p.MaxPTOrder).Select(Function(p) New With { p.MDTID, p.PatientID, p.CareID, p.MDTDate }).FirstOrDefault
Dim nextMDTID = d?.MDTID
Dim nextPatientID = d?.PatientID
Dim nextCareID = d?.CareID
Dim nextMDTDate = d?.MDTDate
```

Putting the `Select`/`FirstOrDefault` on the definition of `d` ensures that any database is only queried once for the minimally needed data. You could leave the `Select` off if the row size is small, or the row only has those four properties. You can use the obvious fluent query translation for `d` if desired.

NOTE: If you don't want some of the variables to be `Nullable`, use `If`:

```
Dim nextPatientID = If(d?.PatientID, CType(Nothing, Integer))
```